# FIltrar enum pelos primeiros valores

Tags: c#, linq, enums

Tenho um Enum e preciso filtrá-lo por seus primeiros valores, excluindo o último.
Por exemplo:

```
 public enum Enum
    {
       
        ENUM1= 1,
        
        ENUM2= 2,

        ENUM3= 3,

    }
```

preciso carregar esses valores numa ViewBag excluindo **Enum3**, qual melhor meio de fazê-lo com LINQ/métodos próprios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer usando linq.

Veja:

```
public class SelectListItem {
    public string Text {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}

       var enumlist =  Enum.GetValues(typeof(Enum)).Cast<Enum>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = v.ToString(),
            Value = ((int)v).ToString()
        }).Where(x => x.Value != "3");
    
    foreach(var enumItem in enumlist)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(enumItem.Text);
    }
```